# What is a generic name for SVN's "trunk", "tags" and "branches" directories?

Tags: svn

The recommended Subversion directory layout contains `trunk`, `tags` and `branches` directories:

```
Project
|-branches
  |- ...
|-tags
  |- ...
|-trunk
```

Is there a generic name for referring to the three directories: `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches`? Let's say for naming a variable: `list x = ["branches/...", "tags/...", "trunk" ]`.)

Comment: I'm not sure that there is, I guess just pick one that makes sense to your project and stick with it, e.g. `projectDirs` or `repoDirs`. Or given that there's only 3 and have specific functions, you could just name them explicitly and forget the list.

Comment: I think repoDirs is as good as any.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it called the *common repository layout*. See [Use a sane repository layout](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html) and [Repository Layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout).

So, I guess you could call them the *common repository layout directories*. (That is not much shorter than enumerating them though.:-)

So, for naming a variable: `commonRepoDirs` or `common_repo_dirs` (depending on the conventions of your programming language).

Answer (score 0):

Base on what I observed in different open source projects, I usually use this convention (Assume we are adopting trunk-based development, and making use of release-branch and feature-branch branching strategies)

Basic layout:

```
+ proj-name
  + trunk        // trunk
  + tags         // tags
  + branches     // release branches
  + sandboxes    // feature branches
```

Directory name for trunk/tags/branches are pretty standard.  I usually separate feature branches from release branches to avoid confusion.  However there is no standard directory for feature branches.  "sandboxes" are one name that I have seen.  You can consider something else you like

For tag name, quite a lot of project use `proj-name-VERSION`.  For example, tag for `foo` project version 1.2.3 is going to be tagged as `foo-1.2.3`

For branch name, it depends on how you arrange your version and release.  One typical way is having version as MAJOR.MINOR.MICRO.  Incrementation of MAJOR or MINOR is going to be a new release, while MICRO is used for bug fixes for a release.  In such case, we usually create release branch for MAJOR.MICRO.x.  For example, upon release of `foo` version 1.0, you should create a release branch for `foo` version `1.0.x`.  Branch name is usually `foo-1.0` or `foo-1.0.x`

For feature branches, simply name it base on the feature.  No special convention I observed.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, I was not intending to ask for "How to name your versions?" but rather how to refer to `branches`, `tags`, and `trunk`. It is a pity because I think your answer is high quality but does not fit my question.

Comment: oh you means something like special "name/label" in svn client to refer that? (just like we use `^` to represent root of project, `HEAD` for the head version?)  If so, I don't think there is any special name/label for them.  Use of these names are just convention and there is actually other conventions